# Android failed to find Build Tools revision X

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After a fresh reinstallation of android studio (which was working prior to reinstall), I get the following error when I open the project

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find Build Tools revision 25.0.3
```

As you can see in the SDK platform picture, I have installed API levels 28, 25, 21 and 16. So, what is missing here?

[image]

UPDATE:

You can also see that only build tool 28 is available in SDK tools according to the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

click on SDK tools and check show package details. Then download that particular build tool version which is throwing the error. Hope this helps!

Comment: There is no toolset 25 there. I see build tools 28 only.

Comment: can you please post an image of all the build SDK tools with show package details checked?

Comment: I told you to check the show package details check box. Who will do that?

Comment: OK I saw that. Thanks.